# Suspend works as shutdown

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management

Closing the lid, going on the desktop to "gear"->suspend, or from terminal level calling `suspend`, `pm-suspend`, or `systemctl suspend` ... all of this ends up with switching off the system.

One-by-one: I try to suspend the system and it goes black (as it should) immediately. There is no indication of powering off. When I press the trackpad (or open the lid) to wake-up, the system do full boot up (restart?). This is strange since if the system would be "truly" off it would not turn-on on trackpad press (or lid action).

Editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` is not effecting anything. Also, there is nothing worrying in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` after pm-suspend.

All of this happened after I `ppa-purge` the `oibaf/graphics-drivers` (re-installing this PPA also doesn't solve the problem).

P.S.
My machine: Dell XPS 9350 with Intel graphics

Comment: I just did. The same effect: the system do full boot-up on wake up. (* I edited the question to include this *)